# Flutter - My keyboard pops out, out of nowhere and when it shouldn't?

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard, provider

I have a problem in my app...

I have an game app that needs to implements players at the beginning of the app. So in the first page called PlayerSelectionPage, you can add players to the game. Then you can choose a game mode. Anyway, when I go to settings and I switch the Language of the game, my keyboard pops out for no reason... I think it's somehow related to my PlayerPageSelection and the fact that it rebuild all with providers to change the language.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my SettingsPage code :

```dart
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String _status = '';
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double index = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context).getDrinkIntensity();
    if (index == 0) {_status = AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_status_1');}
    else if (index == 1) {_status = AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_status_2');}
    else if (index == 2) {_status = AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_status_3');}
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_title')),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assessment),
            onPressed: () {
              HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StatsPage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: 'Stats page')));
            },
            tooltip: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_stat_hint'),
            iconSize: 25,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Center(child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_drink_text'), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2)),
          Center(child: Text(_status, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontSize: 10))),
          Slider(
            value: Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context).getDrinkIntensity()/2,
            onChanged: (val) {
              HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
              Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context, listen: false).setDrinkIntensity(val);
            },
            divisions: 2,
            label: _status,
          ),
          Divider(height: 20),
          Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_lang_title'), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'fr',),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'en', isBeta: true,),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'de', isEnabled: false,),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'es', isEnabled: false,),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'pl', isEnabled: false,),
          LangSelection(langCode: 'it', isEnabled: false,),
          Text("Flag icons made by Pixel perfect from www.flaticon.com", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontSize: 10), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          Divider(height: 20),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_reinitialize_text'), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.restore),
              onPressed: () => Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context, listen: false).resetSharedPreferences(),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(height: 20),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my PlayerSelectionPage:

```dart
class PlayerSelectionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int itemCount = Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context).getPlayerList.length;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_title')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: 'Home page')));
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.chevron_right,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: itemCount > 0 ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                PlayerDismissible(index),
                Divider(
                  height: 0,
                )
              ],
            );
          }) : Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_empty_text'), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2)
      ),
      bottomSheet: BottomPlayerBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

And the BottomPlayerBar (Where I show the keyboard or not:

```dart
class BottomPlayerBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomPlayerBarState createState() => _BottomPlayerBarState();
}

class _BottomPlayerBarState extends State<BottomPlayerBar> {
  String playerName;
  FocusNode myFocusNode;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    myFocusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 80, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 25, left: 20, right: 70),
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          onChanged: (val) => playerName = val.trim(),
          onSubmitted: (val) {
            if (playerName != null && playerName != '') {
              Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context, listen: false).addPlayer(playerName);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
              myFocusNode.requestFocus();
            } else {
              myFocusNode.unfocus();
            }
          },
          maxLength: 19,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_hint'),
              fillColor: Colors.white),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myFocusNode.dispose();
  }
}
```

Any help is welcome !

Thanks !

Edit :
Here is my LangSelection() class :

```dart
class LangSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  String langCode;
  bool isBeta, isEnabled;

  LangSelection({@required this.langCode, this.isBeta = false, this.isEnabled = true});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: () {
        if (isBeta) {
          Provider.of<AppLanguageProvider>(context, listen: false).changeLanguage(Locale(langCode));
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((value) => EasyDialog.showInfoDialog(
            context: context,
            title: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_beta_dialog_title'),
            content: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settings_page_beta_dialog_content'),
          ));
        } else if (!isEnabled) {
          EasyDialog.showInfoDialog(
            context: navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context,
            title: AppLocalizations.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).translate('settings_page_disabled_dialog_title'),
            content: AppLocalizations.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).translate('settings_page_disabled_dialog_content'),
          );
        } else {
          Provider.of<AppLanguageProvider>(context, listen: false).changeLanguage(Locale(langCode));
        }
      },
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset('assets/images/flags/$langCode.png'),
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('lang_$langCode'), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
        trailing: isBeta ? Text("(beta)", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontSize: 10),) :
        !isEnabled ? Text("(disabled)", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontSize: 10),) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you defined `LangSelection()`?

Comment: I've added my LangSelection Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer by my self. As @Crazzygamerr said

> The problem is with calling requestFocus() in your bottomAppBar's initState(). Whenever you rebuild your widget it gets called.

So I did this :

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent) {
        myFocusNode.requestFocus();
      }
    });
  }
```

In the initState of my BottomPlayerBar. What `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` does is that it waits the build of the class so I can have access to the `context`. Then, with `ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent`, I check if the BottomPlayerBar is displayed for the user, if it is, I give the focus and the keyboard appears, if not, it does nothing... So my keyboard doesn't appear anymore when I switch the language.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with calling `requestFocus()` in your `bottomAppBar's initState()`. Whenever you rebuild your widget it gets called.

Try either removing the line and adding it elsewhere or making the widget implement `AutomaticClientKeepAliveMixin` and setting the keepAlive to true.

Comment: It already extends Stateless or stageful widget so I can't extend two classes

Comment: My bad, you have to implement (using ```with```) and not extend it. Look into the docs, it might help